# SVN Redirect cycle

Tags: apache, svn, centos, repository

so ive installed SVN on my centos 6.5,  version 1.6.11
and im trying to configure that in /var/www/html/svn/testrepo will be my repository, 
so i found alot of guides in google and used all of them to try to do that, 
here is my subversion.conf

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so

#
# Example configuration to enable HTTP access for a directory
# containing Subversion repositories, "/var/www/svn".  Each repository
# must be both:
#
#   a) readable and writable by the 'apache' user, and
#
#   b) labelled with the 'httpd_sys_content_t' context if using
#   SELinux
#
#
# To create a new repository "http://localhost/repos/stuff" using
# this configuration, run as root:
#
#   # cd /var/www/svn
#   # svnadmin create stuff
#   # chown -R apache.apache stuff
#   # chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t stuff
#


<Location /unixmen1>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /var/www/html/svn
# Require SSL connection for password protection.
# SSLRequireSSL

      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Subversion repos"
      AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-users
      Require valid-user

</Location>
```

now i checked and i found out that /etc/svn-pass and /etc/svn-auth-users are the same ...
also i dont see svn folder in /var/ which is weird because it is shown in all of the guides, 
i tried those guides : 
http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-svn-subversion-server-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Subversion

just cant figure wht the hell ive done wrong ... 
and by the way this is the first time i try to setup svn ...

**EDIT:**

now after i played with it for a bit i can access via browser the whole directory but i cant connect to the repo with tortoiseSVN i get an redirection cycle error 
and the httpd/access log says :

```
 192.168.1.36 - - [19/Nov/2015:14:44:19 +0200] "OPTIONS /svn/unixmen1 HTTP/1.1" 301 319 "-" "SVN/1.9.2 (x64-microsoft-windows) 
serf/1.3.8 TortoiseSVN-1.9.2.26806"
```

this was in the error log :

```
    [Thu Nov 19 14:40:38 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 SVN/1.6.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Nov 19 14:44:04 2015] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Nov 19 14:44:09 2015] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Nov 19 14:44:09 2015] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Nov 19 14:44:09 2015] [notice] Digest: done
[Thu Nov 19 14:44:09 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 SVN/1.6.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

and i changed the subversion.conf file aswell (edited the file above) 
the etc/svn-auth-users got 1 user in it but the svn doesnt even require credentials, just says that there's a redirection cycle for the URL : 
192.168.1.14/svn/unixmen1

```
[root@SVN svn]# cd /var/www/html/svn/unixmen1/
[root@SVN unixmen1]# ls -als
total 36
4 drwxr-xr-x 7 apache apache 4096 Nov 19 12:43 .
4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root   4096 Nov 19 09:47 ..
4 drwxr-xr-x 2 apache apache 4096 Nov 19 09:47 conf
4 drwxr-sr-x 6 apache apache 4096 Nov 19 09:47 db
4 -r--r--r-- 1 apache apache    2 Nov 19 09:47 format
4 drwxr-xr-x 2 apache apache 4096 Nov 19 09:47 hooks
4 drwxr-xr-x 2 apache apache 4096 Nov 19 09:47 locks
4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root   4096 Nov 19 12:43 project1
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache  229 Nov 19 09:47 README.txt
[root@SVN unixmen1]#
```

would really appreciate if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Show `DocumentRoot` for Apache's mainhost. I suppose, it's below `/var/www/html/svn/` and it's big error
2. I see `cd /var/www/html/svn/unixmen1/`, i.e **virtual** path from `<Location>` exist as real physical path (and even inside DocumentRoot??? - see p.1) - this is giant NO-NO

Common rules (dirty short draft) for Apache-served SVN-repos

1. Repositories places at any location outside web-root
2. DAV-Location doesn't exist as real path inside DocumentRoot (unique name)
3. SVNParentPath used for serving family of repositories with common 1-st parent, SVNPath - for serving single repo

I.e, f.e.:

- `var/repos/Name1 ... var/repos/NameN` are paths to repositories
- `var/www/html` is DocumentRoot
- URL for the repos have to be smth. like `http://HOST/repositories/NameX`

your configuration will be (relevant part)

```
# if mod_dav was compiled as a shared object (instead of statically linked)
LoadModule dav_module         modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule
LoadModule 
...
<Location /repositories>
   ...
   SVNParentPath /var/repos/
   ...
</Location>
```